# retrieve the URL images from SQlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When retrieve the images from Firebase to SQlite it comes as link, so I am trying now to show the images through Picasso as the following:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage())
            .into(viewHolder.food_image);
```

but the image not showing. How can I do it?

Comment: can you past your Image URL

Comment: post your image path which getting into load method.

Comment: this is the URL:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eat-it-recipe.appspot.com/o/images%2Fmeat.jpg?alt=media&token=3162810a-1d38-47e1-98aa-c7dcb302074e

Answer (score 1):

The first check value of this `favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage()`, if not null, paste url to browser and see result. Check your image in xml file and maybe Picasso library error, because in one of my project, Picasso not working but when I using Glide, it's work fine, and i don't understand why :D. BTW you should set placeholder for image.

Comment: i tried it with other field (Text Field) its not null and get the image URL. and the URL working fine when i get the data from Firebase, that's why i surprised